Decided to quit PhD officially. Want to tell my advisor and fellowship coordinator and minimize them getting upset. How can I do so?
After a series of posts, I've finally decided to call it quits on my PhD. I don't have a job lined up now nor a backup plan, but I don't feel like I need one given that I'm working with vocational rehabilitation to find a job that uses my Bachelor's and my Master's already. This would remove my immediate source of stress and provide huge relief for me.
Now, I have to broach this to my advisor and fellowship coordinator. To be clear, my fellowship coordinator is part of an initiative in my state (I'm in the US) to increase diverse faculty and staff. They included neurodiversity as part of diversity, equity, and inclusion now, so that's why I got it. I fulfilled my service requirements via a visiting position last academic year and was awarded $11k that I have saved right now and that I did not touch. The only other condition is that I must graduate with my PhD to keep the money. However, this is a meager amount in the long run.
How do I bring this all up to them in a professional way? I'm also not sure if I should bring up my frustrations with the department (i.e., budget cut plans without telling the students, lack of funding, etc.) and my advisor only telling me the next thing he wants without the end goal in mind (i.e., moving the goalpost all the time). I'd like to know what to do.
Edit: I did see the link to the other post about quitting for a job. I don't have one lined up though, that's the thing. There's also been a lot of drama that I didn't start and found myself caught in the middle of quite often. I want to at least try and make it clear why I left so the next students with MS degrees (since all Psychology PhD programs will be cut at some point in the near future. Clinical got cut first) don't have to go through it at all.

sorry you're going through this. I think the linked question has an answer to you question.

@RichardErickson I don't have a job lined up right now, that's the thing. I'd also like to still have a connection with him if that would be possible too. He's already tenured so he won't lose anything with me gone, but that doesn't change my department hates my guts and I want to mitigate the damage as much as possible by having them understand my side of the story.

I understand that. However, the accepted answer to the question seems to work in your situation as well: Ask to have a face-to-face meeting with your advisor. Be honest about your reason(s). People on the internet cannot have a difficult conversation for you.

@RichardErickson I see now. That's fair reasoning. I'll sit on whether there's anything else that differentiates my question. One of the main things I want is for students to not have to go through what I did again in this case.
